# Separate lines in FacetGrid plot so that all lines only connect to its respective group

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am attempting to recreate this plot using Python 2.7 and Seaborn:

[image]

As you can see each facet has a time-series plot for each country in that continent and the lines only connect points within its respective country (group).

Here is my code so far, for some reason I cannot figure out how to get the lines to only connect within their group and not all interconnect to each other:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = 'https://python-graph-gallery.com/wp-content/uploads/gapminderData.csv'

def add_cols(grp):
  grp['popl'] = grp['pop'].apply(lambda x: x/10**5)
  grp['gdp_wt'] = np.average(grp['gdpPercap'], weights = grp['pop'])
  grp['pop_wt'] = sum(grp['pop'])
  return grp

dat = (pd.read_csv(url)
         .query('country != "Kuwait"')
         .groupby(['year','continent'])
         .apply(add_cols))

f = sns.FacetGrid(dat, col='continent', hue='continent')
f = f.map(plt.plot, 'year', 'gdpPercap', marker='o', group=dat.country) # Attempting to assign group here but it's not working
f = f.map(plt.plot, 'year', 'gdp_wt', c='k', marker='o')
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

Here is my current plot and you can see what I mean by all points being interconnected:

[image]

This graphic was originally created using `R` and `ggplot2`. My next attempt will be creating the black lines with a weighted variable in my dataset. I'm unsure if this is impossible using `Seaborn`. Also, as a heads up, I am aware of the `ggplot` module available for Python, but don't want to use that at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `hue` to `country` and use a palette:

```
# map continental to color
colors = {con:color for con, color in zip(df.continent.unique(), ['r','b','g','m', 'b'])}

# create palette by country name
pal = {country:colors[con] for country, con in set(zip(df.country, df.continent))}

# use the palette
f = sns.FacetGrid(dat, col='continent', hue='country', palette=pal)
f = f.map(plt.plot, 'year', 'gdpPercap', marker='o') # Attempting to assign group here but it's not working
f = f.map(plt.plot, 'year', 'gdp_wt', color='k', marker='o')
plt.show()
plt.clf()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realize `hue` and `col` were different things.